When does a set of real numbers have a minimal element?
I Believe the answer is when the set is closed in the sense of standard topology (we exclude $\mathbb{R}$) itself.
Examples:

Point sets have a minimum, and they are closed.

Closed interval also have a minimum, which is simply the lower bound $[a,b]->a$


If my guess is right, how do I prove it, else what is the correct characterization?
I'm guessing this has something to do with well orderedness. What I got so far from MSE:

Well orderedness is preserved under subsets

Well ordered subsets must be countable



$(-\infty, 0]$ is closed, but it does not have a minimal element...

$[0,1)$ is not closed, but it does have a minimum element.

Suppose that $X\subseteq (0,\infty)$, then ${0}\cup X$ has a minimum and you can  choose $X$ to be as complicated as you want it to be.

also, being well ordered is not the same as having a minimum element.

There is no topological characterization: $[0, \infty)$ has a minimum element, $(-\infty), 0]$ doesn't, but $-$ is a homeomorphism of $\mathbb R$, which maps one to the other.
Similar for well-ordered.

I feel like this question got downvoted just because it does not have a very good answer. But that is not the fault of the OP.

There isn't really a simpler answer than "having a minimum" itself. Being Euclidean closed and bounded below is certainly a sufficient condition, but by far not a necessary one.

It's sufficient for $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ to be compact, but this is not necessary (the example $[0, 1)$ applies).

This question unfortunately does not have an interesting answer. It also doesn’t have an answer based on the topology (as shown by @Ulli)
Here is the nicest description I could come up with :
$$\{\{x\} \cup Y_x | x\in \mathbb{R}, Y_x \subset (x,\infty)\}$$
is the collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with a least element.

In other words, a subset of $\mathbb R$ has a least element if and only if it has a least element.

@HagenvonEitzen exactly. This (hopefully) makes it clear that there is nothing of interest in this question.
